# Is there a JavaScript equivalent of get_post_field?

Tags: hooks

I recently installed `@wordpress/hooks` so that I could use applyFilters on the react side of my plugin, but I'm looking for something for `get_post_field` as well. I haven't seen it in any of the NPM packages that I've found. Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 1):

The `@wordpress/hooks` package only gives you a JS-like equivalent to the PHP-based hook system in WordPress - they are entirely separate, and don't bring any native WP PHP functions to the table.

What you need (most likely) is an AJAX request to the [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/).

Specifically, the [`GET posts` endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#retrieve-a-post), which by default is:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/<post_id>
```

That will retrieve a JSON object representation of the post. An example JS function using `fetch` might look like:

```js
async function get_post_field( post_id, field ) {
    const restUrl = document.querySelector( 'link[rel="https://api.w.org/"]' ).getAttribute( 'href' );

    const response = await fetch( `${restUrl}wp/v2/posts/${post_id}` );

    const post = await response.json();

    let value = await post[ field ];

    if ( value.rendered !== undefined ) {
        value = value.rendered;
    }

    return value;
}

const title = await get_post_field( post_id, 'title' );
```

This code assumes you're running it in the context of a default WordPress page (since it grabs the base REST API URL from the `<link rel="https://api.w.org/" />` tag added in the `<head />`.

Comment: Oooh, so @wordpress/hooks doesn't actually use available filters from wordpress? That explains a little bit. As for the other part of your answer, thanks for the code. I do know how to put together what I need. I just misunderstood @wordpress/hooks and thought maybe there was a JS function available.